# gorm sql structure tag shrowing syntax error

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a very simple model, and I am trying to declare a field to be `UUID`, so I did something in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486511/how-do-you-do-uuid-in-golangs-gorm)

```
type UserUpload struct {
  gorm.Model

  UUID string `sql:"type:uuid"`
}
```

in my `main.go`

```
client.DB.AutoMigrate(&models.UserUpload{})
```

But I get:

```
[2020-08-19 04:41:44]  Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uuid , PRIMARY KEY (`id`))' at line 1
```

Any ideas?
MySQL version:

`mysql  Ver 8.0.21 for macos10.15 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

Comment: Are you sure `uuid` is a valid *type* in mysql?

Comment: good question, I am actually trying to specify it as an uuid field, and I did something in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486511/how-do-you-do-uuid-in-golangs-gorm

Comment: That question's about postgresql and postgresql does have a `uuid` type. Doing a quick search for "mysql uuid type" seems to suggest that mysql does not have such a type, it does have a function named as such however for storing the actual values one has to use an alternative type.